# d3.js node translation does not work when changed the node to image

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to centralize the node when I clicked it, so I used the following code:

```
    node.on("click", function(d){
        var cX = width/2;
        var cY = height/2;
        var dx = cX - d.x;
        var dy = cY - d.y;
        link.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + dx + "," + dy + ")"; });
        node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + dx + "," + dy + ")"; });
    });
```

It works for the "normal node", but when changed the node to image, the link is moved while the node (image) is still here.

[image]

Here is my example: http://talk.huacishu.com/t11.html

I know a little bit about `d3js\javascript`, anyone can tell me where is wrong?

Comment: There might be a conflict with the tick function of your simulation. An svg element can't have two transform attribute so i think that your g element containing the image + text is transformed by click function but it is immediately overwritten by the tick function.

Comment: You are right, that seems to be the problem.I'm trying to find  another way to center the node.Thanks a lot for your help:-)@FredericKuhner

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it by another way :
Using "var g_container = svg.append(g) "
to append a "g" label(g_container), and move the "g_container" to centralize the clicked node.

here is the final project:
https://myaisv.github.io/curry/renlifang/connan/t1.html

[image: final project]